# Indexing time of smart search increases heavily

Tags: joomla-3.x, smartsearch

I have a large site with over 900.000 articles. Now I want to use smart search.

Therefore I use the CLI method to index the smart search:

```
php -d memory_limit=256M finder_indexer.php
```

No matter how large I set the batch size there is always the same problem. After a couple of hundred batch processess the duration increases heavily.

**Example:**

```
Processed batch 280 in 4.186 seconds.
Processed batch 1511 in 10.186 seconds.
```

Do you have any idea what the problem is and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Smart Search functionality has been improved in Joomla 4. You are using Joomla 3 and the **Joomla 3 support ends on 17 August 2023**.

Maybe you could test if an **upgrade to Joomla 4** solves your issue?
I would create a copy of the website, install it at another place (e.g. local computer), and test the performance with Joomla 3 + smart search on the local computer.
After that I would migrate that test environment to Joomla 4 and test again.

Alternatively you could consider using **Elasticsearch**, a distributed, RESTful search engine optimized for speed and relevance on production-scale workloads. There's a commercial Joomla plugin available that integrates Smart Search with ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative search engines for Joomla are also discussed in more detail here: [Joomla 4 Smart Search: Extra database for indexing data](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/32251/joomla-4-smart-search-extra-database-for-indexing-data)

Answer (score 0):

Our strategy is to avoid Joomla's search altogether - it is generally made for small sites and it is slow and inefficient, and it'll put a huge strain on the website when someone searches for something - especially for a website as large as yours (as a rule [that we follow], one should not use Joomla's built-in search features for sites with over 10K articles).

As peter mentioned - Elasticsearch is one good alternative. Another good alternative is Sphinx, which we use for our clients. [This guide](https://www.itoctopus.com/using-sphinx-to-substantially-enhance-the-speed-of-the-joomla-search) for installing Sphinx on a cPanel/WHM server (and making it work with Joomla) that we have written ages ago still works (it has really stood the test of time) - I believe some minor alterations to in search plugin must be made to make it compatible with Joomla 4 (but you're using Joomla 3, so it should technically work for you).